# Bootstrap Reactjs field alignment

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a reporting website with multiple graphs and a twitter feed. Currently, the website looks something like this: [image]

However, there are two graphs being pushed into a different part of the screen by the twitter widget.[image]

I would much prefer these graphs to fill the space under the larger graph. The current DOM structure for the main part of the application is like so:

```
<div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
        <div className="row">
            <TitleBar/>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-8">
                <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-4">
                <TwitterCard/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-4">
                <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-lg-4">
                <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished by nesting.

1. Put a new `row` inside the `col-lg-8` column and then
2. Put your graph columns inside that new row.

Note that in this newly created/nested row you now have 12 column units to work with.

So, the first nested column gets the class `col-lg-12` and the smaller get the class `col-lg-6`.

```
<div className="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-8">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-4">
            <TwitterCard/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also important to note:

Your `<TitleBar/>` sits directly inside a Bootstrap `row`. This is not allowed in Bootstrap. Only a Bootstrap column can be an immediate child of a Bootstrap row. So, you must put at least one column inside that row (can be just `col`) and then put your `<TitleBar/>` inside that column.

Comment: Also, if you want to remove the padding, you can add the `no-gutters` class to the titlebar `row`.